# removeFromSuperview doesn't work with UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I add an image to my view by the following code if the count is zero and remove it otherwise:

```
var coverImageView = UIImageView()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if count == 0 {
        let coverImage = UIImage(named: "AddFirstRecord")!
        coverImageView = UIImageView(image: coverImage)
        coverImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 5, width: tableView.frame.width-20, height: 100)
        view.addSubview(coverImageView)

    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.coverImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it adds the image to the view, but  `removeFromSuperview` does not work. (I made sure that it reaches to the `else` condition by debugging). I did the process in the main queue as well to be sure that the problem does not relate to threads. I wonder where is the origin of the issue?

Comment: Are you updating count after Navigating from other Controller back to same Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` the view still is not prepared completely to view. So removingFromSuperview does not have any effects. Instead, we should do the action inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count == 0 {
        let coverImage = UIImage(named: "AddFirstRecord")!
        coverImageView.image = coverImage
        coverImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 5, width: tableView.frame.width-20, height: 100)
        view.addSubview(coverImageView)

    } else {
        coverImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) :

> viewDidLayoutSubviews()
>   Called to notify the view controller that its
>   view has just laid out its subviews.
>
> **Your view controller can override this method to make changes after
>   the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this
>   method does nothing.**